# PHP session is working on localhost but not on actual server

Tags: php, html

i'm having trouble to pass session variable to another page. It is working on localhost but not on server. I would want to pass $_SESSION['user_check'] to editpasswordsignup.php but whenever i click submit, $_SESSION['user_check'] is empty.

This is loginsignup.php

```
<?php

include('db.php');

session_start(); 

?>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper-bg">
<div id="wrapper-bgtop">
  <div class="container" id="header">
    <div class="container" id="logo">
      <h1><a href="indexhomepage.php"></a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="page">
    <div id="loginbox">
        <form action="" class="formbox" method="post">
        <label>Email Address:</label> 
        <input class="box1" name="email" type="text"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>Password:</label> 
        <input class="box2" name="password" type="password"> 
        <a class="myButton1" href="forgetpassword.php">Forgot Password</a><br>
        <input class="submit5" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"> 
        <a href="signup.php" id="myButton2">Create Account</a>
        </form>

            <?php

            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
            $email =   ($_POST["email"]);
            $password =($_POST["password"]);

            $_SESSION['user_check'] = $_POST["email"];

            $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email'  ");

            $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

            $drawemail = $row['email'];

            $drawpassword = $row['password'];   

            if (($drawemail == $email ) && ($drawpassword == $password ))

            {
            ?>
            <script>window.location = "../wordsignup.php";</script>;

            <?php
            }

            else 
            {
            echo "wrong password or username";
            }
            }

            ?>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="footer-content-bg">
    <div id="footer-content">
      <ul>
        <li class="footer1">
          <a href="aboutus.php">About us</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="termandcon.php">Term and Conditions</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="privacyadvertising.php">Privacy Advertising</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="policy.php">Policy</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="userargeement.php">User Agreement</a>
        </li>
      </ul><br>

      <div id="copyright">
        © . All Rights Reserved.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is editpasswordsignup.php

```
  <?php 

  include('db.php');

  session_start();

  $user_check = $_SESSION['user_check'];

  ?>

 <div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper-bg">
<div id="wrapper-bgtop">
  <div class="container" id="header">
    <div class="container" id="logo">
      <h1><a href="indexhomepage.php"></a></h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="page">
    <div id="forgetpassword">
      <div style="font-size:20px; color:#000080; font-weight:bold; border-width:1px; border-style:none; width:600px; margin:10px 0px 0px 175px;">
        Edit Password
      </div>

      <div style="font-size:16px;border-style:none; width:560px; margin:20px 0px 10px 175px; font-weight:bold;">
        Please enter your old password below and we will send you your password.
      </div>

      <div id="forgetpasswordbox">
        <form class="forgetpassword" method="post">
        Please enter your old password<br>
        <input class="oldpassword" name="oldpassword" type="password"><br><br>
        Please enter your new password<br>
        <input class="newpassword" name="newpassword" type="password"><br><br>
        Please re-enter new password<br>
        <input class="confirmpassword" name="confirmpassword" type="password"><br><br>     
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="send">
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" id="footer-content-bg">
    <div id="footer-content">
      <ul>
        <li class="footer1">
          <a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="termandcon.php">Term and Conditions</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="privacyadvertising.php">Privacy Advertising</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="policy.php">Policy</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="userargeement.php">User Agreement</a>
        </li>
      </ul><br>

      <div id="copyright">
        © . All Rights Reserved.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <?php       
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {               
    $oldpassword = $_POST['oldpassword'];
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword']; 
    $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword']; 

    $sql = mysql_query (("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='user_check' AND password='$oldpassword' "),$conn);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $email = $row['email'];
    $selectpassword = $row['password'];

    if ($oldpassword == "")
    {

    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("pls enter your oldpassword")';
    echo '</script>';
    exit;
    }

    if($newpassword=="")
    {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("pls enter your newpassword")';
    echo '</script>';
    exit;

    }

    if($confirmpassword=="")
    {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("pls enter your confrimpassword")';
    echo '</script>';
    exit;

    }       

    if (($oldpassword) != ($selectpassword)) 
    {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("No user exists with this password  '.$selectpassword.' ")';
    echo '</script>';
    exit;
    }

    if ($newpassword == ($confirmpassword))
    {   
    mysql_query("UPDATE user SET password = '".$newpassword."' WHERE email='".$email."'");

    $message = "Your password ".$newpassword." and click the link uploadsignup.php to upload your photo";   

    mail($email, "Change Password", $message);
    ?>

    <script>

    alert("Password Successfully change...!!!!\nClick OK to upload photo\nNewpassword will send to your email address");
    window.location="uploadsignup.php";

   </script>   


    <?php
    }
    else 
    {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("new password does not match")';
    echo '</script>';

    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: don't you destroy the session in 'db.php'?

Comment: Try to echo the redirect script out, instead of closing PHP and opening it again. Like that: `if (($drawemail == $email ) && ($drawpassword == $password ))
            {
            echo '<script>window.location = "../editpasswordsignup.php";</script>';
      }`

Comment: The issues here are all user generated. You seem to have copy/pasted lots of different code from different places - for example some SQL is mysql and other SQL is pseudo- Object Orientated.

Answer (score 2):

As you said it's working on localhost and not on the particular server, you might have a different settings in `php.ini`. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: Reading the OP code there are various user mistakes rather than issues with SESSION setup.

Comment: I agree, but when the same code works on localhost, I assume the problem could be somewhere else...

Comment: yes, fair point. The information given by the OP indicates a Session config issue, but the code displayed by OP clearly shows numerous syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

I once had this problem for hours. My sessions worked on localhost but were not passing from page to page. The issue was the comments I had above the session starting. For some reason it didn't affect localhost but my server was just not having it.

So if there is anyone else reading this post with this issue, this is something else you can try.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, maybe give an example of the problematic code and exactly what you did to fix it?

Comment: I removed the comment above the session_start() and it worked fine after that.

Comment: This comment saved my life. I removed the comments above session_start() and everything worked. Just like you said, you can get away with comments above session_start() on local server but not on remote. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php session_start();
-----
-----
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try it still the same. Pls help to solve this problem. i really need a session pass through

Comment: This is a very short answer, essentially just a small code dump. Please explain why you think this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that need to be corrected here:

1) Do not use styles in the page, use CSS classes and Id's rather than Styles. I have edited the question to remove these as they get in the way of the real code we're interested in.

2) Do not use MySQL, it is ***deprecated*** meaning it is no longer supported and the reason it is no longer supported is there are various flaws and security issues and I HIGHLY recommend looking into MySQLi or PDO as alternative methods of connecting to a database. Seriously.

3) Your issue is syntx - we'll start with brackets - see:

```
$email =   ($_POST["email"]);
$password =($_POST["password"]);
```

Should be:

```
    $email =   $_POST['email'];
    $password =$_POST['password'];
```

You do not need to put values in brackets when assigning variables. Also note that array values are in single quotes `'` **not** double quotes. So:

```
$_SESSION['user_check'] = $_POST['email'];
```

Will work better, alternatively try this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['email'])){
$_SESSION['user_check'] = $_POST['email'];
}
else {
$_SESSION['user_check'] = "No Email value given in form";
}
```

to replace the above line.

4) Your HTML code is incomplete, your form has no `action` value in the second code block, these things are probably not critical but this code is ripe for errors due to being ambiguous.

5) At the top of editpasswordsignup.php (after session_start) put this:

`var_dump($_SESSION['user_check']);` and with the above code from point 3, this should give you an output.

6) Check your SQL:

```
$sql = mysql_query (("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='user_check' AND password='$oldpassword' "),$conn);
```

Your email value is a string, not a variable. Your SQL here is also a complete mess, what is the reason for this?

replace the above with:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$user_check' AND password='$oldpassword' LIMIT 1");
```

Complete all of the above and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the op question and the answer needed why code is working on local host and not server the correct answer seems by Arun.
Too bad he has been down voted but that could be because he has not explained anything in his answer.

I have met this problem before.
The solution is make sure you do not have space above or below

```
   <?php
```

line.
I am fairly certain that is why Arun has drawn lines to indicate your other php code should follow emediately.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I ended here. Even though I don't see there `session_set_cookie_params()` maybe you've typed it on `db.php`. Because of using `LOCALHOST` on `session_set_cookie_params(time()+600,'/','LOCALHOST',false,true);` session didn't work, so if you used `session_set_cookie_params()` you have to make sure you've replaced `LOCALHOST` with your domain